# Diagonalization of Matrix with Trigonometric Functions

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

**Problem statement:**

Diagonalize the following matrix:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \theta & \sin \theta \\
\sin \theta & -\cos \theta\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

**My attempt:**

Ie found that the eigenvalues of this matrix are $\lambda = -1$ or $\lambda = 1$, so I plugged in $\lambda = -1$:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta+1 & \sin\theta \\
\sin\theta & -\cos\theta+1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y \\
\end{pmatrix}
= 0
$$

I tried to solve this, but I got $2x\sin\theta=0$. How do I find the eigenvectors?

Comment: If your calculation is right, $(0,1)$ is an eigenvector.

Comment: @Shuchang How did you calculate that?

Comment: Your equation requires $x=0$, and thus $y$ is arbitrary nonzero.

Comment: $$\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&-\cos\theta)\end{pmatrix}\binom 01=\binom{\sin\theta}{-\cos\theta}\neq-\binom 01$$ *unless* $\;\theta= 2k\pi\;$ ...I don't understand neither the OP's solution $\;2x\sin\theta =0\;$ nor Shuchang's claim that it is required $\;x=0\;$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\;\lambda=-1\;$ :

$$\begin{align*}I&\;\;(\cos\theta+1)x+\sin\theta y=0\iff y=-\frac{\cos\theta+1}{\sin\theta}x\\II&\;\;\sin\theta x-(\cos\theta-1)y=0\end{align*}$$

We need only one equation as these two are linearly dependent (proof?), so

$$II\longrightarrow x=\frac{\cos\theta-1}{\sin\theta}y\;\implies\binom {\frac{\cos\theta-1}{\sin\theta}}{y}\;\;\text{is an eigenvector,}\;\;\theta\neq k\pi\;,\;k\in\Bbb Z$$

Something similar happens if $\;\lambda=1\;$

Comment: Thanks, I got it wrong indeed.